# Why I obtain this error message when from a dialog I try to perform a function defined into the parent page using parent.rifiutaSingolo()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have the following problem trying to perform a JavaScript function from a dialog that is defined into the parent page that opened this dialog.

So I have this situation:

I have a **parent page** page named `autorizzaFattura2` that is the page that open the dialog (when the user click on a link the dialog is opened) by this JavaScript:

```
function openDialog2(pagina,larghezza,lunghezza,tipo) {

//alert("INTO openDialog2(), pagina: " + pagina, " larghezza: " + larghezza + " lunghezza: " + lunghezza + " tipo: " + tipo);

larghezza = '950px';
lunghezza = '470px';
lunghezza2 = '530px';
if (tipo == 3) {
    larghezza = '950px';
    lunghezza = '470px';
    lunghezza2 = '530px';
}

if (tipo == 9) {
    larghezza = '950px';
    lunghezza = '470px';
    lunghezza2 = '530px';
}
        unitaLargo = larghezza.substring(larghezza.length - 2, larghezza.length)
        unitaLungo = lunghezza.substring(lunghezza.length - 2, lunghezza.length)

        var puntiLarghezza = 0;
        var puntiLunghezza = 0;

        if (unitaLargo != "px") {
            //per default è in percentuale
            Wlargo = (screen.width * larghezza) / 100;
            puntiLarghezza = Wlargo;
            Wlargo = Wlargo + "px";
        } else {
            Wlargo = larghezza
            puntiLarghezza = larghezza.substring(0, larghezza.length - 2);
        }

        if (unitaLungo != "px") {
            //per default è in percentuale
            Wlungo = (screen.height * lunghezza) / 100;
            puntiLunghezza = Wlungo;
            Wlungo = Wlungo + "px";
        } else {
            Wlungo = lunghezza
            puntiLunghezza = lunghezza.substring(0, lunghezza.length - 2);
        }

        var l = (screen.width / 2) - (puntiLarghezza / 2);
        var t = (screen.height / 2) - (puntiLunghezza / 2);

        DialParam = 'width=' + Wlargo + ',height=' + Wlungo + ',toolbar=no,directories=no,';
        DialParam = DialParam + 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,copyhistory=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no';

        //alert("pagina: " + pagina);
        pag_aperta = window.open(pagina, 'popUp_', DialParam);
        pag_aperta.moveTo(l, t);
        pag_aperta.focus();
}
```

So, as you can see, the popup is opened by the `window.open()` statement, this one:

```
pag_aperta = window.open(pagina, 'popUp_', DialParam);
```

OK, into this parent page (`autorizzaFattura2`) there is also defined the `rifiutaSingolo()` JavaScript function, this one:

```
function rifiutaSingolo() {

        alert("Into rifiutaSingolo()");

        chiudi();
        $('#myRejectNote').css("visibility", "visible");
        $('#rifiutaTable').css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#dialogReject").dialog("open");
        document.getElementById('myRejectNote').focus();
    }
```

OK, into the dialog opened by the `openDialog2()` function there is this button that clicked have to perform the `rifiutaSingolo()` function defined into the parent page:

```
<input style="color: #FFFFFF; font: bold 10px tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif" class="bottone" readonly="readonly" type="button" value="Rifiuta" onclick="parent.rifiutaSingolo()">
```

I tried to do it using the `parent`, in this way: `onclick="parent.rifiutaSingolo()"` but it don't work and the `rifiutaSingolo()` function is not performed and in the `FireBug` console I obtain this error message (when I click on the button):

```
TypeError: parent.rifiutaSingolo is not a function
```

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue and correctly perform the `rifiutaSingolo()` function defined into the parent page?

Comment: A JSFiddle would have been convenient for this kind of issue

Comment: you are opening another page you are trying to execute a js code from another page and that is not possible

Comment: @madalinivascu this is absolutly not true !!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself.

The problem was that my dialog was not a real dialog but it was created and showd by **window.open**

```
pag_aperta = window.open(pagina, 'popUp_', DialParam);
```

So to perform the **rifiutaSingolo()** defined into the parent page I can't use this:

```
onclick="parent.rifiutaSingolo()"
```

because it is related to the dialog but I have to use this:

```
onclick="window.opener.rifiutaSingolo()"
```

that is related to the window